# Move xml-layoutupdate on cms-pages, exclude if from the content-area?

Tags: xml, magento, rendering

I’d like to create a cms-page displaying a static block outside the actual content. I’m using the xml-layoutupdate to call the block.

Can I change the position at which the block is rendered?

I’m pretty bad in explaining so I provided some of my output source-code:

[This](http://pastebin.com/jy85yqxg) is what I’m getting at the moment, and [this](http://pastebin.com/WN2tHw3G) is what I’m willing to get in the end.

I’m using Magento 1.5.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

At the point in the page where you want your static block to be inserted - in the content and not the XML update - use [this directive](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags#block_id_block_id):

```
{{block id='block_id'}}
```

Where `block_id` is the static block's identifier.